# How to pass dataframe column of type dtype('<M8[ns]') as parameter to sql query of sql server database in pandas python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, data-analysis

I tried this:

```
 query =  "SELECT * FROM GPSEventsData09 where GPSDateTime Between '%s' and '%s'"
    
 data = pd.read_sql(query, con=engine, params = [new.iloc[0]['StartDateTime'],new.iloc[0]['EndDateTime']])
```

But I am getting an error as follows:

> ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('The SQL contains 0
> parameter markers, but 2 parameters were supplied', 'HY000') [SQL:
> SELECT * FROM GPSEventsData09 where GPSDateTime Between '%s' and '%s']
> [parameters: (Timestamp('2020-09-01 13:26:00'), Timestamp('2020-09-01
> 14:26:00'))] (Background on this error at:
> http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)vv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in SQL, but that's not how you do parameters in SQL. I would actually recommend that you do the parametrizing in Python, and then use the resultant SQL string as-is. It's a bit more direct:

```
query =  "SELECT * FROM GPSEventsData09 where GPSDateTime Between 'start_date' and 'end_date'"
query = query.replace('start_date', new.iloc[0]['StartDateTime'].strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
query = query.replace('end_date', new.iloc[0]['EndDateTime'].strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
data = pd.read_sql(query, con=engine)
```

Comment: I have tried this but it's throwing an error:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-154-d32f3dd7a1da> in <module>
      1 query =  "SELECT * FROM GPSEventsData09 where GPSDateTime Between start_date and end_date"
----> 2 query = query.replace('start_date', new.iloc[0]['StartTime'])
      3 query = query.replace('end_date', new.iloc[0]['EndTime'])
      4 data = pd.read_sql(query, con=engine)

TypeError: replace() argument 2 must be str, not Timestamp

Comment: Then you will need to convert the Pandas Timestamp to a standard SQL-type string - usually mm/dd/yyyy is perfectly adequate. Try something like `new.iloc[0]['StartDateTime'].strftime('%m/%d/%Y')`.

Comment: see this:      TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-157-07ab31766db4> in <module>
      4 new.iloc[0]['EndTime'] = new.iloc[0]['EndTime'].strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
      5 
----> 6 query = query.replace('start_date', new.iloc[0]['StartTime'])
      7 query = query.replace('end_date', new.iloc[0]['EndTime'])
      8 data = pd.read_sql(query, con=engine)

TypeError: replace() argument 2 must be str, not Timestamp

Comment: But I also want time with date by using strftime('%m/%d/%Y') it is only giving date  and my   format  is  date time both and taking this ('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S') throwing an error as follows ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '13'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")
[SQL: SELECT Top 10 * FROM GPSEventsData09 where GPSDateTime Between 09/01/2020 13:26:00 and 09/01/2020 23:15:00]

Comment: SQL syntax probably requires single quotes around the datetime. Try the edit.

Comment: got an output and if I want to pass 'DL-04-CJ-4262' kind of parameter then just taking the parameter  between single quotes say 'reg' will do?

Comment: I have no idea what that kind of parameter is, but absolutely: you can use the `.replace()` function to do that - you likely will need quotes around the word you're replacing.